# My code is breaking out of my for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

so I've been working on this code for a little bit just to test my abilities and I've run into a brick wall. For some reason my code is breaking out of my for loop. If I say I want to see how much 2 rooms cost it goes through the first one fine but them asks me how many rooms I want to check again. If I input 2 again, it will go through it once and then go on through the rest of the code normally. I have two for loops setup the exact same as each other but for some reason one works and the other doesn't. I'm probably making a stupid mistake but I've been trying to fix it for ages now but no cigar. Appreciate all help!

```
def start():

    print ("Welcome to Caroline's Painting and Decorating cost estimator")
    print ("Here you can see an estimate to see how much the job will cost")
    print ("First though, you have to enter a few details about the job")
    customerNumber = input ("Please enter your customer number ")
    dateofEstimate = input ("Please enter the current date ")

def roomCalculator():

    surfaceAreaCost = 0
    totalPrice = 0
    price = 0
    count = 0

    rooms = int(input("Please enter the number of rooms that require painting "))

    for i in range(0, rooms):
        roomName = input ("What room needs decorating? ")
        wallsNumber = int(input("How many walls are in the room? "))
        wallpaper = input ("Is there any wallpaper thats needs to be removed? Enter Y for yes and N for no ")
        if wallpaper == "Y".lower():
            surfaceAreaCost + 70

        for i in range(0, wallsNumber):
            count = count + 1
            print ("Please enter the dimensions for wall", count)
            height = int(input("How high is the wall? "))
            width = int(input("How long is the wall? "))
            surfaceAreaWall = height*width
            wallCost = surfaceAreaWall * 15
            price = surfaceAreaCost + wallCost

        employeeType = input ("What employee would you like? Enter AP for apprentice or FQ for Fully-Qualified ")
        if employeeType == "AP".lower():
            price = price + 100
            print ("You are having an apprentice do the job")
            print ("The price for the", roomName, "without V.A.T is", price)
            return price            
        elif employeeType == "FQ".lower():
            price = price + 250
            print ("You are having a Fully-Qualified employee to do the job")
            print ("The price for the", roomName, "without V.A.T is", price)
            return price
```

Comment: Weird, I ran your code and nothing happened.

Comment: Are using python 3 and in IDLE? If so, I have no idea why

Comment: Oh no its me being stupid again, I haven't copied all of my code. Just a part. The bit I've pasted is just defining functions, its not actually calling them

Comment: You maight want to fix that. I fail to see how you could call those functions in any sane way and have the problem you describe.

Comment: The problem was that at the end of the first for loop I call the beginning of the function again. The code I posted and was having trouble with is different to the one I had at school. I only found that out today :/ Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the help! It was a stupid error on my part. I used 3.4.4 at my school computer and 3.5.1 at home. It all worked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is a result of nested for loops, because you use variable i in both. This causes an error since you change value of variable i in first for loop with second for loop. Rename variable in second for loop with j for instance.